# CN3722 solar controller - What MOSFET should I use?

Tags: mosfet, solar-charge-controller

I need to know what P-channel MOSFET to use with a CN3722 to charge two 18650 batteries.

[The datasheet](http://www.consonance-elec.com/pdf/datasheet/DSE-CN3722.pdf) doesn't say what MOSFET to use.

My solar panel parameter are:

- maximum power 10w
- maximum operating current 0.57 Amp
- maximum operating voltage 18.5 volts

My batteries are two 18650 2600 mAh in serie.
(8.4 volts in maximum change voltage)

On datasheet say The MOSFETs such as AO4459, STM9435(or WT9435), AO3407A can be used.

But AO4459 different type of the one from the CN3722 typical application diagram:

mosfet on the typical diagram of CN3722:

[image: CN3722 typical diagram]

AO4459 symbol:

[image: AO4459]

Currently I use Si4435DYPbF Power MOSFET but didn't work because not stop charging after the full charge already reach and DONE led are on.

This are symbol of my current mosfet.
[image: current symbol]

This are my current schematic
[image: current schematic extract.]

Comment: Not everyone shows the intrinsic body diode of a MOSFET in the circuit diagram symbol, if that is your concern.

Comment: Understand Andrew. but also the line is continued in the first symbol and also the line going out is to the left in first symbol and the second is to the right.

Comment: Diego, the two symbols are the same type of device. Please rest assured about that. MOSFET symbols can be very confusing because people use them without thinking. The bulk diode will be in both of those devices despite it not appearing to be in one of them symbolically. You are looking for a p channel enhancement mode MOSFET if you want the full technical name. I'm in the UK so I probably won't be answering for another few hours until morning. Are you still trying to find a device without a bulk diode or,  are you looking for a device with pins that are swapped to suit your Pcbs?

Comment: The chip requires a p channel enhancement mode MOSFET to be clear. You have no choice other than to use this type of device. Can you also state in your latest question what incoming voltage supply range you expect to use and, how much battery charging current is needed during charging. Pleas add this detail to your question above.

Comment: Andy thanks for your interest. I edit the question with the information you ask.

Comment: BTW I want to buy a TO220 or similar on my local market to "update" my boards and then update the PCB when I make new orders form PCB manufacter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I need to know what P-channel MOSFET to use with a CN3722 to charge
> two 18650 batteries*

The data sheet says several things about the MOSFET choice but, right at the bottom of this data sheet extract below are some recommendations: -

[image]

Pick a MOSFET that has enough drain-source maximum voltage to cover the input voltage supply needed to charge 2 series batteries. Also double check that the chip is capable of handling two batteries of the voltage you need and that the maximum supply voltage for the chip isn't exceeded.

Comment: Andy I edit the question with some images

Comment: Diego, you should consider accepting an answer to your previous question if you want help from me on this question. This is protocol.

Comment: Sorry Andy I am new here. Already accepted. I really appreciate your help here.

Comment: @DiegoSerrano please formally accept my answer or explain why you cannot do so.

Comment: This had gotten tangled up in my inkwell. It's already accepted. Thanks.